# Solving $ \log_3 (6x+2) - 2\log_3 (x)=2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms, roots

I am trying to find the value of $x$ ... but I'm absolutely stuck, some hints would be appreciated!

$$ \log_3 (6x+2) - 2\log_3 (x)=2 $$

My work so far:

$$\begin{align*}
\log\left(\dfrac{6x+2}{x^2}\right) &= 2^3\\
6x+2 &= 8x^2\\
-8x^2+6x+2 &= 0\\
x = 1,&\quad x = \dfrac{1}{4}
\end{align*}$$

But I've tested with $1$ and $\frac{1}{4}$, and it's never equals to $2$ ...

Where's my error?

Thanks !

Comment: Note: $\ln$ is usually reserved for the natural logarithm. To talk about logarithms of base $a$, we use $\log_a$, not $\ln_a$.

Comment: Note that $\ln$ is reserved for the natural logarithm. If you want to specify a base, write $\log_3(\cdots)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Snap!

Comment: @Jonathan: That second line is still wrong; that should be either $\log_3(...) = 2$, or drop the logs and have $3^2$ (not $2^3$).

Comment: You knew what to do, I think. There was carelessness about the notation for $\log_3$, and carelessness can turn an easy right answer into a wrong one.  In the line in the original that says $\ln((6x+2)/x^3)=2^3$ the $\ln$ was probably unintended, since you recovered from it on the next line. The $2^3$ is probably a slip of the tongue for $3^2$, natural since one sees $2^3$ a lot more often than $3^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's logarithm base 3, so your second line should read:

$$\dfrac{6x+2}{x^2} = 3^2$$

Note also that you have exponentiated, so there should be no $\ln$ anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you got the first line; you should have
$$\log_3\left(\frac{6x+2}{x^2}\right) = 2,$$
not the natural log and not equal to $2^3$.

Then you would conclude from this that
$$3^{2} = \frac{6x+2}{x^2}.$$
Note in particular that you get $3^2$, not $2^3$. The logarithm base $3$ is what the *exponent* needs to be, not what the base needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

It is when
$$
\mathrm{log}_3 (6x+2) - 2 \mathrm{log} (x) = 2 \longrightarrow \log_3 \left( \frac{ 6x+2}{x^2} \right) = 2 \longrightarrow \frac{6x+2}{x^2} = 3^2 = 9.
$$
When you get rid of logarithms you must take "3 to the both sides".

Answer (score 1):

You can't just drop the $\log_3$, so it should be $\log_3 \left( \frac{6x+2}{x^2} \right) =2$ which leads us to $6x+2=x^2 \cdot 3^2 =9x^2$.

Now you can go on the way you did: $-9 x^2+6x+2=0$ which is the case if and only if $x= \frac{1}{3} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Edit: I replaced $\ln$ by $\log_3$ in my answer and subsequently changed the results of the calculation.